# PHP 7, Imagemagick and CircleCI

Tags: php, laravel, imagemagick, circleci

Does anybody know how to install php 7 with ImageMagick on CircleCI?

Everything except ImageMagick works. Here is the error message I get.

```
Intervention\Image\Exception\NotSupportedException: 
ImageMagick module not available with this PHP installation.
```

Here is my **`circle.yml`**

```
machine:
  pre:
    - sudo apt-get update; USE_PRECOMPILE=true sudo -E circleci-install php 7.0.4
  php:
    version: 7.0.4
  timezone: America/Los_Angeles

  services:
    - mysql

  environment:
      APP_ENV: testing
      APP_KEY: randomrandomrandomrandomrandomra

dependencies:
  pre:
    - sudo aptitude -y install imagemagick
    - sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php
    - sudo apt-get -y update
    - sudo apt-get -y install php-imagick

  override:
    - composer install --prefer-dist --no-interaction

  post:
    - mv .env.circleci .env

test:
  override:
    - vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Answer (score 3):

To get imagick working with PHP 7 you need to use the following in your `circle.yml`:

```
machine:
  php:
    version: 7.1.3

dependencies:
  pre:
    - printf "\n" | pecl install -f imagick
    - echo "extension = imagick.so" >> /opt/circleci/php/$(phpenv global)/etc/php.ini
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it using suggestions from these two posts...

From this [post](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/how-to-install-php-imagick-php-extension/19051/4?u=geneowak) from the circle-ci discussion forum, you'll need to install with PECL and then enable with docker-php-ext-enable

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends \
    && pecl install imagick \
    && docker-php-ext-enable imagick
```

if it fails to activate the extension you may add this after/instead of `docker-php-ext-enable imagick`

```
echo "extension=imagick.so" | sudo tee -a /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/ext-imagick.ini
```

For that, you can refer to this [github comment](https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/105#issuecomment-129318769)